# Black lines after booting into Windows 10 from grub

Tags: windows-10, grub

I have an annoying problem: I installed Parrot Os(debian distro for pentesting) and from that point, when I boot from the grub to Windows 10, sometimes some black lines appear slowing the login screen of Win10. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank you guys.